# How to send a colored excel to outlook email using powershell

Tags: html, excel, powershell

i have an excel that has format (eg color based on value, merged cells, borders etc), and i want to send it as email body using powershell.

1. I tried to format it as html save locally, then send using powershell, but i only got a line of error in the email body

> This page uses frames, but your browser doesn't support them

my code:

```
    Start-Process Outlook
$o = New-Object -com Outlook.Application
$mail = $o.CreateItem(0)


$mail.HTMLBody = "<span style='font-family:Courier New;font-size:12pt'>"   # Due to blank space problem
$mail.HTMLBody += Get-Content I:\SCRIPT\IPCNewScript\ResultFinal.html 


$mail.cc = *****
$mail.To = *****
$From = ****
$mail.subject = "test"

$mail.save()
```

2. maybe i can read cell by cell from the excel, and convert into html format and send as email. but there are lots of color(for example, if head column is 'Sunday', and the column value is 0, then use yellow color), cell merge, table etc, so i can not simply use ConvertTo-HTML.

Any suggestions? i tried to upload pic of my excel but it doesnt seem to work here. The hyperlink leads to an error page

Comment: add as an attachment?

Comment: Why are you trying to send this in the XLS as HTML in the eMail body vs as an attachment? Depending on who you are sending it to, they could have their email set for text only and this would never render anyway. Embedded web pages are a know and in most enterprises an unacceptable security risk. If you are sending this to MSOutlook users, if you cannot embed this in Word, it will not work in Outlook, since Outlook uses Word as its render engine and editor, unless the user changed that in some way.

Comment: @postanote Thanks for advise. That was an requirement though to send as email body so that it's easier for everyone to check. people tend to ignore if it's an attachment - that's the truth.

Comment: @Ctznkane525  Send as email body is the requirement unfortunately.

Comment: No worries and understood. Yet, again, your first test is to take the XLS HTML and try to directly open it in Word and then copy and paste in the a Word doc. If that fails, then it is not doable in Outlook since it is using Word to render anything you put in the eMail body. Back in the day, circa Outlook 2K7, you could create web templates for embedding web pages. That is gone in recent Outlook versions. The more complicated the web page, the more Outlook/Word will refuse to render it.